# MVC 3 - Updating table row with EDMX model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, edmx

I've tried several ways to update an object in my database. I've also read a couple of questions out here and other forums concerning updating data. But except for one way nothing else is working for me.

What works? If I update all attributes manually it works. Something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateModel(Person person)
{
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
    var p = db.PERSON.Single( x=> x.ID == person.ID);
    p.NAME = person.NAME;
    p.AGE = person.AGE;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

But for models with a lot of attributes this isn't really an option. Is there someway I can do something simular to this?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateModel(Person person)
{
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
    var p = db.PERSON.Single( x=> x.ID == person.ID);
    p = person;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I know that there are a lot of questions out there similar to mine but i'm just not able to let this to work for me.

Comment: download the nerd dinner application and pour through the source. Also - dispose of your DBEntities() by enclosing it in using(DBEntities db = new DBEntities()){ .... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateModel(Person person)
{
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
    var p = db.PERSON.Single( x=> x.ID == person.ID);
    TryUpdateModel(p); <--here is the change i made
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.tryupdatemodel.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot men. I'm happy i've asked the question. It just took me 2 hours of looking up stuff. I was thinkin too complex. :)